# BS4 and urllib: gather some links and store it in an array

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I am attempting to gather some data on the cost of living index for some towns in USA/Texas  getting it from the website below: http://www.city-data.com/city/Texas.html

Approach: for the sake of repeatingly extract links out of the targetpage i use the function below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

def getLinks(url):
    r = requests.get("http://www.city-data.com/city/Texas.html")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    links = []

    for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
        links.append(link.get('href'))
##It will scrape all the a tags, and for each a tags, it will append the href attribute to the links list.

    return links

print( getLinks("http://www.city-data.com/city/Texas.html") )
```

**dataset:** http://www.city-data.com/city/Texas.html that contains the following pages that hold information about the towns with inhabitants:

```
Abilene, TX 120,958 
Abram-Perezville 6,663 
Addison, TX 15,457 
Alamo Heights 7,806 
Alamo, TX 19,224 
Aldine 15,869 
Alice, TX 19,395 
Allen, TX 94,179 
Alton North 6,182
```

note: what is aimed to gather the data out of the sub-pages: therefore i need a parser that loops through the subpages - eg like the following:

> http://www.city-data.com/city/Abilene-Texas.html
> http://www.city-data.com/city/Abram-Perezville-Texas.html
> http://www.city-data.com/city/Addison-Texas.html
> http://www.city-data.com/city/Alamo-Heights-Texas.html

and so forth - but at the moment i get back

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BeautifulSoup'
```

**PS:** in the first attemt i used urllib2 - but this is python2 - so i changed it to urllib3
but i am not sure if this is correct - and if i have this module running in my Anaconda. This is pretty important. **By the way**: what about the following term: urllib2.urlopen - that seems to be outdated too!? I need to re-write this also.  What do you think!? Look forward to hear from you!
At the moment i am a bit confused about the urllib.urlopen-term!?

**update:** thanks to the hint of Andrej and  Guilherme, i saw that i have the following setup in the packages:

[image]

so i need to recode the plugins that i import. Many thanks for the hint!

Comment: Change to `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Comment: @Andrej Kesely hello dear Andrej  many thanks for the hint. By the way: what about the urllib2.urlopen - that seems to be outdated too!? I need to re-write this also.  What do you think!? Look forward to hear from you!

Comment: Hint: do not use `urllib2`. Much, much better library with good API is `requests`

Comment: many thanks for the hint: i will try to rewrite this part of the code. I will have a closer look at the manpages.  Thank you dear Andrej - youre just great!

Comment: hi there dear Andrej - i am glad to see your awesome work - note i have some lines of code where i struggfle with  - see also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76362600/getting-data-out-of-clutch-co-with-bs4-and-requests-failed
 i am trying to figure out - can you help here - thanks in advance!! You rock!! keep up the great work  ps: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76409097/driver-webdriver-chrome-issues-with-a-selenium-approach-how-to-work-aro

look forward to hear from you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Run the pip list command on your terminal and ensure that a Beuatifulsoup library is installed.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7Pwn.png)

```
C:\Users\xxxx>pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- ----------
beautifulsoup4         4.8.2
```

Comment: hello dear Guilherme - many many thanks - i have put the output of the pip-request in the update. Later the evening i will re-run the code.  I have to hurry to catch the train now. Many many thanks for all you did!

Comment: again -  thanks for the hint. By the way: what about the urllib2.urlopen - that seems to be outdated too!? I need to re-write this also.  What do you think!? Look forward to hear from you!

Comment: hello @zero ! Sorry for the delay in replying.  As Andrej replied, use the request library instead of urllib2. I believe you have already managed to resolve it.