# driver = webdriver.Chrome() :: issues with a selenium approach - how to work around

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Well - i am trying to figure out the simplest approach to gather data from clutch.io

- i have tried various approaches to gather data from a website (clutch.io )  but all seems to fail:

see here

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://clutch.co/it-services/msp'

driver.get(url=url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")

links = []
for l in soup.find_all('li',class_='website-link website-link-a'):
    results = (l.a.get('href'))
    links.append(results)

print(links, "\n", "Count links - ", len(links))
```

throws back this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4f37092106f4> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 from selenium import webdriver
      3 
----> 4 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
      5 
      6 url = 'https://clutch.co/it-services/msp'

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    243                 alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    244             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 245         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55a6ebf424e3 <unknown>
#1 0x55a6ebc71c76 <unknown>
#2 0x55a6ebc98757 <unknown>
#3 0x55a6ebc97029 <unknown>
#4 0x55a6ebcd5ccc <unknown>
#5 0x55a6ebcd547f <unknown>
#6 0x55a6ebcccde3 <unknown>
#7 0x55a6ebca22dd <unknown>
#8 0x55a6ebca334e <unknown>
#9 0x55a6ebf023e4 <unknown>
#10 0x55a6ebf063d7 <unknown>
#11 0x55a6ebf10b20 <unknown>
#12 0x55a6ebf07023 <unknown>
#13 0x55a6ebed51aa <unknown>
#14 0x55a6ebf2b6b8 <unknown>
#15 0x55a6ebf2b847 <unknown>
#16 0x55a6ebf3b243 <unknown>
#17 0x7ffb30c27609 start_thread
```

how to work around!?
Well - i am trying to figure out the simplest approach to gather data from clutch.io

Comment: You need to pass the path to your chromedriver

Comment: dear Celius Stingher - i love to hear from you again .

Comment: Hi @malaga, was undetected Selenium's answer not helpful?  Thanksfor adding that you are running this in a google-colab environment. Is there something else that should be taken into account before I try to provide an answer?

Comment: hello dear Celius: many thanks for your reply. No afaik nothing helped so far. i am wondering why i cannot work out this on Colab: see besides this approach all the others: 
a. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76401453/
b. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76401129/
c. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76389587/
d. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76362600/

Look forward to hear from you.  BTW i am workin on a Anaconda-setup here - but this takes some time - if colab-approaches fail all the time - i try to work it out on anaconda. Love to hear from you. Regards

Comment: hi there dear @CeliusStingher - do you have any ideas to go ahead here!?

Comment: @Celius Stingher i would love to hear  from you again  - have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to find the [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) binary in the default location of your system or it wasn't installed at all.

---

### Using a Chrome executable in a non-standard location

You need to override the default *Chrome binary location* with the ***custom location*** as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" # as per my Win10 OS box
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get('http://google.com/')
print("Chrome Browser Invoked")
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary error with Selenium in Python for older versions of Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50140554/7429447)
- [Is Chrome installation needed or only chromedriver when using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62449076/7429447)

Comment: hello dear undetected Selenium - many thanks - i am currently trying to get this working in my google-colab environment - so that it works on my goal  - to gather data from clutch...